# After putting two lines to export variables in .bashrc, getting `-bash: /home/user1/.bashrc: Permission denied`?

Tags: command-line, permissions, windows-10, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Running Windows Linux Subsystem's Ubuntu, and I am trying to get Xfce working based on this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/827956

So, in my .bashrc, I put the following lines:

```
export DISPLAY="localhost:0"
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

However, every time I start up WLS bash, I get: `-bash: /home/user1/.bashrc: Permission denied`

If I then type in `echo $DISPLAY`, I don't see the string I set it to, so there's definitely something going wrong exporting the variables in .bashrc.

What might the issue be? Here's my current .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export DISPLAY="localhost:0"
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

The result of `ls -l ~/.bashrc`:

`---------- 1 user1 user1 3828 Jan 18 19:51 /home/user1/.bashrc`

Comment: Post your current `.bashrc` here please.

Comment: @muru ok, i have posted it as an edit.

Comment: Can you post the results of `ls -l ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @muclux I have added that in as an edit too!

Comment: `chmod u+rx ~/.bashrc` will give you the permission to run the script.

Comment: @muclux Yup, this works! Could you write an answer explaining why this is the case? I would like to accept it as the answer :) (in particular, can you explain what changed after adding the two lines that I did, making it so that I had to reset permissions?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you showed at the end of your question your .bashrc could not be read nor executed by anyone.

`chmod u+rx ~/.bashrc` gives the owner (user1) the right to read and execute.
Read `man chmod` for further details.

Comment: But why did .bashrc only mess up in terms of permission after I edited it?

Comment: How did you edit it? No editor that I know would remove all permissions from the edited file.

Comment: I used notepad++

Comment: @user89 Editing WSL files from Windows applications is **not supported**. See https://askubuntu.com/a/828689/158442, https://askubuntu.com/a/759885/158442.

Comment: I didn't check what Windows editors do to WSL specific files, but normally it is not recommended to edit Linux files in Windows (the reverse works better).